# Jar deployment in Netbeans - howto?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, java-7

I've created Java app in Netbeans,
today I moved that app into Maven project,

I've created all dependencies in `pom.xml`, and application builds succesfuly and runs as before Maven migration.

However I have problem with deployment,

I was trying to use that [Deployment of artifacts with FTP (Maven Deploy Plugin)](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html) but after inserting Netbeans project is broken.

My questions are:

What is easiest way to copy jar and maven files to some server by ftp or scp after pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> in Netbeans (build button),

also how to run that app? before Maven I was using WinSCP to copy jar file, I've copied also lib directory with dependencies and I was using:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

Can Maven on remote host use java7 not system java? 
I have jdk7u4 untarred on server, and I'm using that to run my application.
Can maven invoked by command line be handled by system java, but run application from java7 or I have to have only java7 in PATH?

Can Maven be bundled to single jar so I can run:

```
maven app.jar PARAM1 PARAM2..
```